# Configure buildbot for builders with diamond dependencies

Tags: dependencies, continuous-integration, buildbot, diamond-problem

Say, I have a project with 4 different jobs (builders):

1. Library
2. Binary A (dependent on Library)
3. Binary B (dependent on Library)
4. Package (dependent on Binary A and Binary B)

and I would like to setup Continuous Integration using BuildBot. At the moment I use `Triggerable` schedulers to trigger Binary A and Binary B builds once Library has been rebuilt. At the same time `Triggerable`s are used to trigger Package build once Binary A or Binary B has been rebuilt.

This setup is works okay in case of changes made to either Binary A or Binary B. But when changes made to Library, I've got triggered builds for Binary A and Binary B. And each of them triggers Package rebuild, as a result Package has been rebuilt twice. Is there a way to overcome this issue in Buildbot?

In other words I would like to get Package to be rebuilt only once after both Binary A and Binary B has been rebuilt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one Builder that checks out and builds all 4 things, serially.

Comment: yeah. I'm actually used serial solution for a while. But in our case Binary A and Binary B are both long-compiled components and it's preferable to build them in parallel.

Comment: You could have a top-level build that does three things: (1) build library; (2) trigger builds of A and B and wait-to-finish; (3) build package.

Comment: thanks. Provided solution actually solves case in the question.